# How to make Live Templates (snippet) work in JetBrains Rider C#?

Tags: c#, jetbrains-ide, rider

Any idea how to make Live Templates work in JetBrains Rider C#?

For example, when I type `cw` it doesn't show any snippet. Please have a look at the screenshot. I tried different sections of the program and many other snippets, but none works. Settings seems to be OK.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution! If the page is clear, it doesnt work, you need to add at least one variable.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I'd seen here is that they did not work reliably with top level statements. If I created an explicit program class instead, they started working reliably.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).